# Insert Doubly Linked list in C by only one function

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to work on insert function by doubly linked list in C. I could find how to do it by doing `insert_head` and `insert_tail` but is there any way that we can have only one function `insert(int num)` and insert the numbers? (not sorted, just displayed by order) so this is what I have set:

```
struct node {
int data;
struct node *next, *prev;
}*head;

void insert(int num) {
struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof (struct node));
// doubly linked list

}
```

Comment: Insert it where? What is the meaning of *not sorted, just displayed by order* ?

Comment: You can search for `[c] doubly linked` and find plenty of examples here on SO.

Comment: You need to be able to say where to insert. In C++ you always insert before the iterator, which allows you to insert before the first element, and there is a special iterator for "the end", so you can insert before (or at) the end. You can convert these concepts into a lightweight element pointer in c quite easily.